How can I make my API calls more reusable using the AppAuth library?
To get my feet wet with SwiftUI app development I'm making a simple app with login functionality using the AppAuth library. I've got basic login and logout functionality working and can make a request using the received access token. Currently all requests are made from a single class. For a real app I'd like to split the requests and have them in different files. This is how I'm making a basic API request to fetch the user's data after they have logged in:
class AuthStore: ObservableObject {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    private var authState : OIDAuthState?
    
    @Published var isAuthenticated = false

    func getUserData() {
        let userEndpoint = URL(string: "https://example.com/my-api/user/1")!
        
        self.authState?.performAction() { accessToken, idToken, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error fetching fresh tokens: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                return
            }
            
            guard let accessToken = accessToken else {
                return
            }
            
            // Add Bearer token to request
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: userEndpoint)
            urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(accessToken)"]
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
                
                print("Performing patron information request")
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
                        self.patron = decodedData
                    } catch {
                        print("JSON Decoding error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            task.resume()
    }
}

How can I make API requests that require the access token more generic and reusable? One of the solutions I was thinking was using generics, something like this:
func getData(url: URL) -> T {
        self.authState?.performAction() { accessToken, idToken, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error fetching fresh tokens: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
                return
            }
            
            guard let accessToken = accessToken else {
                return
            }
            
            // Add Bearer token to request
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(accessToken)"]
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
                
                print("Performing patron information request")
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                        self.patron = decodedData
                    } catch {
                        print("JSON Decoding error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            task.resume()
    }
}

Or would it be better to add a method to the AuthStore class that returns a fresh access token that can then be used somewhere else to make the request?

If you don't have restrictions to use external libraries then I will suggest using Alamofire it's the best networking library on GitHub for Apple's app development. Also, it supports all platform and you can integrate it in your app with CocoaPods, SPM or Carthage it support all dependency manager.
To make your code more reusable you can follow this Article which adds a layer to the Alamofire request and it's probably the cleanest and most organized network layer you can write for your app.
You can prefer this code snippet as well
